# How do I add jquery selectable to a custom jquery ui?

Tags: jquery-ui

Any object I try to apply the `.selectable()` I get the following error:
`Object doesn't support property or method 'selectable'`. Assuming this is happening because the `selectable` ui feature  wasn't downloaded when I made my custom jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js script, I opened my jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js file and sure enough at the top the selectable feature is not shown

```
* Includes: jquery.ui.core.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.ui.mouse.js, jquery.ui.position.js, jquery.ui.draggable.js, jquery.ui.resizable.js, jquery.ui.button.js, jquery.ui.datepicker.js, jquery.ui.dialog.js, jquery.ui.tooltip.js
```

I downloaded the full jqueryui (1.9.2) package, opened selectable.js and copied the contentents and pasted them into my custom jquery script. I still get the same error. I tried closing/opening Visual Studio and doing a rebuild.

Here is how I'm attempting to apply the selectable UI property.

```
$("#myList").selectable();   //apply to <ol> object
```

Here is how I'm loading the script in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<link href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Thank for looking.

Comment: As a workaround I just added the full jquery-ui.js to my project and added it as another `<script>` tag. Sloppy workaround but it will have to do for now.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make another custom jquery-ui script with selectable included?.. BTW, the problem could be in the browser cache - did you try to clean it after changing the js file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I spent a lot of time tweaking the color scheme on the ui download so I was trying to avoid doing it again. Perhaps I could still re-download it and preserve the ui-css file. Also, RE: "the problem could be in browser cache"-- very Helpful!. I was later dealing with an issue where the selectable items on my page would cause an exception when clicked... but only on IE. clearing the cache fixed it. +1 to your comment @pckill